# Populate dojo datetextbox value using jquery

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, dojo

I am using dojo datetextbox in my zend form, how can I insert a value in it using JQuery?

For example

```
$("#myDate").val('15-01-2014');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
dijit.byId("myDate").set('value','15-01-2014');
```